# did i put too much yeast in?

Tags: beer, yeast, first-time-brewer, brewing, taste

this is the beer i made

ingredients:

- 17 litres spring water
- 1 can of coopers Australian pale ale i think it was 1.7 kg normal size
- 500 grams malt extract
- coopers brew enhancer 1 which is 250 grams maltose and 250 grams dextrose mixed
- 25 grams Amarillo hops and 6 grams goldings hops
- dry 97 american west coast yeast 11 grams
- cooper DIY yeast 7 grams

hope its not to much yeast!

steps

1. heated 3 litres off spring water
2. tipped into fermenter
3. dissolved 1 can of coopers australian pale ale
4. meanwhile boil 2.5 litres of spring water for hops.
5. add 3 litres heated water to fermenter and disolved in he malt extract 500grams and coopers (brew enhancer 1 a 50/50 maltose dextrose mix 500grams
6. stired thoroughly until all parts were broken
7. add 25g Amarillo hops and 6g golding hops to step fours boiling water
8. boiled hops for four minutes
9. strained hop water into fermenter and mixed through
10. filled fermenter the 17 litre mark with spring water
11. allowed beer to get to 26 degrees added 11 grams of dry 97 american west coast yeast and 7 grams DIY coopers brewing yeast

The O.G. was 1072. How low does everyone think the F.G. will be? Did I over do it with the yeast by putting in two packets of the stuff

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did no harm by adding all that yeast, but it very likely was unnecessary.  The 11 gram yeast pack by itself would have been sufficient.  The 7 gram would not.  It's pretty hard to predict FG accurately unless you've made a recipe several times.  If I was to shoot in the dark, I'd guess you'll finish in the mid 20s.  But that's only a guess.

Comment: how does extra yeast effect the beer will it utilise more sugars so theirs a lower fg or will it make the beer less sweet

Comment: The fermentability of the beer is pretty much set by the wort you make.  While using too little yest may result in a higher than expected FG, using too much will not necessarily make it lower.  Using more yeast may increase the level of esters in the beer, but that's not a certainty.

Comment: i didn't make a wort though? and what are esters? thanks heaps for your help by the way denny :) –

Comment: Yes, you did make make wort.  That's what it's called before it becomes beer!  Esters are the fruit like aroma and flavors in your beer.

Comment: the F.G. is 22 and the O.G was 72 making this quite a bit stronger then intended 6.75 ABV do you think this beer will be ok to drink??

Comment: There's a lot more to "OK to drink" than simply the OG and FG, but based on those I don't see any reason it wouldn't be OK to drink.

Comment: ok so the recipe sounds ok??

Comment: Other than boiling the hops in water (not a good idea IMO), the recipe seems fine.

Comment: why is their so much sediment in my beers

Comment: There could be several causes, but the first question is how much do you think is too much?  Is it more than other beers you make?

Comment: its just too bitty. theirs about 1.5 cm of yeast at the bottom of each 650ml bottle why do you think this could be

Comment: I can only make guesses.  Maybe becasue there was no boil.  Maybe because you boiled the hops in water, not wort. Boiling the hops in the wort causes the polyphenols in the hop to cause the proteins in the wort to "clump" and fall out more easily.  since you didn't boil, yo didn't get that happening in your kettle where you could leave it behind.  I dunno for sure...like I said, I'm just guessing.  Have you made this beer before with different results?

Comment: so your saying that its a good idea to poor you wort in the kettle and boil it, then when i poor the wort in the fermenter through a strainer it would collect the sediment? haven't made this beer before its only been in the bottles for 16 days do you think the sediment could disappear a bit mite sound like a stupid question.

Comment: their was sediment at the bottom of my fermenter so i stored it while bottling so the sediment was stirred all the way through, maybe i should have just left it at the bottom of my fomenter ?

Comment: Yep, I think you've found the problem!  You're supposed to siphon the beer from om top of the "trub", leaving all that stuff behind in the fermenter.  Live and learn.